# Rails create join table object should not create but update in special case

Tags: ruby-on-rails, join

In a webshop I have a booking that needs to know if a booking already exists in the order. I had the whole thing working, but then the details...

...now 'booking on a product' (or in normal English: Adding a product to your shopping-cart) adds a totally new booking on the order list in each case. It oughtn't when this product is already booked once, then it only should alter the quantity.

So easy right? Just one simple if-statement and the whole thing works.

**bookings_controller.rb**

```ruby
  def create
    @order = current_order
    # If product has already been booked
    if @order.bookings.where(product_id: params[:product_id]).exists?
      # Then: Only alter the quantity in the booking.
      @booking = @order.bookings.where(product_id: params[:product_id])
      @booking.product_quantity = params[:product_quantity]
    else
      # Else: Make a new booking.
      @booking = @order.bookings.new(booking_params)
      @product = @booking.product
      @booking.product_name = @product.name
      @booking.product_price = @product.price
    end
    @order.sum_all_bookings 
    @order.save
  end

  # ...

  def booking_params
    params.require(:booking).permit(:product_quantity, :product_id)
  end
```

Doesn't seem to work.

How do I make the check in the if-statement? 
Or should I go about a whole different route to update the booking?

**Edit**

I've tried various combinations in this shape after gmcnaughton answer. I get either multiple entries still or no entries at all. This one gives me no entries at all.

**bookings_controller.rb**

```ruby
  def create
    @order = current_order
    @booking = @order.bookings.find_or_create_by(product_id: params[:product_id])
    product = @booking.product
    if @booking.new_record?
      @booking.product_name = product.name
      @booking.product_price = product.price
    else
    @booking.product_quantity = params[:product_quantity]
    @booking.save
    @order.sum_all_bookings 
    @order.save
  end
```

Should I also control the booking `id` maybe? But this makes no sense, because in the case of finding an existing booking it should be there already.

Is it maybe that I am firing the bookings through a `remote: true form`?

**Edit 2**

Also not working:

**bookings_controller.rb**

```ruby
  def create
    @order = current_order
    @booking = @order.bookings.where(product_id: params[:product_id]).first_or_initialize
    if @booking.new_record?
      @booking.product_id = params[:product_id]
      product = @booking.product
      @booking.product_name = product.name
      @booking.product_price = product.price
    else
    @booking.product_quantity = params[:product_quantity]
    @booking.save
    @order.sum_all_bookings 
    @order.save
  end
```

**Edit 3**

Maybe this has got something to do with it:

**categories_controller.rb / Shop**

```ruby
def index
    @categories = Category.all.order(name: :asc)
    # Voor het inzien van wat al geselecteerd is.
    @order = current_order
    # Voor het aanslaan van een nieuwe booking.
    @booking = current_order.bookings.new
  end
```

Which basically lays out the whole initial shop. The @booking is there to build the form of every product.

**Following worked:**

```ruby
  def create
    @booking = @order.bookings.find_by(product_id: params[:booking][:product_id])
    if @booking
      @booking.product_quantity = params[:booking][:product_quantity]
      @booking.save
    else
      @booking = @order.bookings.new(booking_params)
      @product = @booking.product
      @booking.product_name = @product.name
      @booking.product_price = @product.price
    end
    @order.save
  end
```

Apparently I needed to grab the params, by adding `[:booking]` like in `params[:booking][:product_id]`. Anybody knows why?

Answer (score 0):

The idea is right, but I think you're missing a call to `.first`:

```
@booking = @order.bookings.where(product_id: params[:product_id])
  => #<ActiveRecord::Relation>
```

should be:

```
@booking = @order.bookings.where(product_id: params[:product_id]).first
  => #<Booking>
```

...otherwise you're updating the relation and not a `Booking` model.  You probably also want to call `@booking.save` after you modify it.

Separately, ActiveRecord also has [`first_or_initialize`](http://apidock.com/rails/v4.2.7/ActiveRecord/Relation/first_or_initialize) and [`first_or_create`](http://apidock.com/rails/v4.2.7/ActiveRecord/Relation/first_or_create) helpers which let you find a matching instance or build/create a new one:

```
@booking = @order.bookings.where(product_id: params[:product_id]).first_or_initialize
if @booking.new_record?
  @product = @booking.product
  ...other stuff for new record...
else
  @booking.product_quantity = params[:product_quantity]
end
@booking.save
```

Comment: I am working with your solution, but whatever I tried so far keeps me ending up with multiple entries.

Comment: Any idea after my last edit? I used your idea, it should work and it is way more elegant... but it doesn't yet.

Comment: `find_or_create_by` and `new_record?` won't play well together - if the find creates a new model, it will already have an id and so `new_record?` will be false. Did `@order.bookings.where(...).first_or_initialize` not work?

Comment: I made an edit 2. Is this what you mean? It doesn't work yet. Maybe the difficulty is in the fact that a booking is a join table between order and product, but I don't see how.

Comment: I also tried `if @booking.product_id.nil?`. The logic looks ok, but something is missing

Comment: I notice that it keeps on making new bookings with a unique id. I still have the same issue after struggling with it for three days. Any idea what is happening?